# Combine and change Table name in a CSV file using php

Tags: php, csv

This is  my first question here so please be patient with me.

So my problem is I have a CSV file and the tables aren't correct.

```
sku;artnr;sku_lieferant;barcode;name;size;date;modifydate;brandid;brand;maincatid;maincategory;subcatid;subcategory;price;b2bprice;b2bsale;discount;vatnl;vatde;baseprice;currency;popularity;stock_lieferant;weeknr;remaining;nova;materialid;material;colourid;color;lxbxh;weight;contents;contents_type;maxdiameter;mindiameter;length;npictures;censorpic;description;mainpic_url;maincatid2;maincat2;subcatid2;subcat2;remaining_quantity;country;battery_required;battery_included;npicturescensor;hscode;meta_title;meta_description;delivery_time;short_description;image;small_image;thumbnail;media_gallery;type;simples_skus;configurable_attributes;tax_class_id;categories;options_container;qty;is_in_stock
```

So What I have is a "maincategory" and a "subcategory" and I need to merge them together into one class called "categories"

so it would look like "/maincatagory/subcatagory" in the table "categories".

At the moment im creating the "categories" with a standard category

```
//set category

$this->_helper->setImportCategories( true );
if ( $this->_helper->getImportCategories() ) {
    if ( empty( $product['categories'] ) ) {
        $product['categories'] = "/newimports";
    }
} else {
    unset( $product['categories'] );
}
```

Is there any way to get the categories written in the CSV file?

Thanks for the help